# Constrain query by multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel

My query:

```
    $units = DB::table('units')
    ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'units.location_id')
    ->join('castles', 'castles.id', '=', 'units.castle_id')
    ->join('unit_types', 'unit_types.id', '=', 'units.unit_type_id')
    ->select('units.location_id',
        'units.previous_location_id',
        'units.id as unit_id',
        'units.castle_id',
        'castles.guild_id',
        'units.unit_type_id',    
        'units.current_health',
        'unit_types.damage',
        'unit_types.range')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('location_id', 'castle_id');
```

results in some test data like this:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "location_id": 1,
            "previous_location_id": 1,
            "unit_id": 2,
            "castle_id": 1,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 3,
            "current_health": 90,
            "damage": 10,
            "range": 3
        }
    ],
    "2": {
        "1": {
            "location_id": 2,
            "previous_location_id": 2,
            "unit_id": 3,
            "castle_id": 2,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 5,
            "current_health": 100,
            "damage": 20,
            "range": 2
        },
        "6": {
            "location_id": 2,
            "previous_location_id": 5,
            "unit_id": 7,
            "castle_id": 5,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 15,
            "current_health": 180,
            "damage": 20,
            "range": 3
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "2": {
            "location_id": 3,
            "previous_location_id": 3,
            "unit_id": 4,
            "castle_id": 3,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 1,
            "current_health": 100,
            "damage": 10,
            "range": 1
        },
        "3": {
            "location_id": 3,
            "previous_location_id": 3,
            "unit_id": 5,
            "castle_id": 3,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 1,
            "current_health": 100,
            "damage": 10,
            "range": 1
        }
    },
    "4": {
        "5": {
            "location_id": 4,
            "previous_location_id": 4,
            "unit_id": 8,
            "castle_id": 4,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 20,
            "current_health": 300,
            "damage": 40,
            "range": 2
        },
        "7": {
            "location_id": 4,
            "previous_location_id": 1,
            "unit_id": 1,
            "castle_id": 1,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 1,
            "current_health": 100,
            "damage": 10,
            "range": 1
        }
    },
    "5": {
        "4": {
            "location_id": 5,
            "previous_location_id": 5,
            "unit_id": 6,
            "castle_id": 5,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 15,
            "current_health": 180,
            "damage": 20,
            "range": 3
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to constrain the query so that I only get the results where `location_id` is the same but `castle_id` is different, which would look like this:

```
{
  "2": {
        "1": {
            "location_id": 2,
            "previous_location_id": 2,
            "unit_id": 3,
            "castle_id": 2,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 5,
            "current_health": 100,
            "damage": 20,
            "range": 2
        },
        "6": {
            "location_id": 2,
            "previous_location_id": 5,
            "unit_id": 7,
            "castle_id": 5,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 15,
            "current_health": 180,
            "damage": 20,
            "range": 3
        }
    },
    "4": {
        "5": {
            "location_id": 4,
            "previous_location_id": 4,
            "unit_id": 8,
            "castle_id": 4,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 20,
            "current_health": 300,
            "damage": 40,
            "range": 2
        },
        "7": {
            "location_id": 4,
            "previous_location_id": 1,
            "unit_id": 1,
            "castle_id": 1,
            "guild_id": null,
            "unit_type_id": 1,
            "current_health": 100,
            "damage": 10,
            "range": 1
        }
    },
}
```

I tried something like `->whereColumn('units.location_id', '<>', 'units.castle_id')` but that didn't work in instances where the `castle_id` happened to have a similar key.

---

*edit*
this raw SQL tells me when I have more than 1 `castle_id` on a given location:

```
SELECT location_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT castle_id)
FROM units
GROUP BY location_id
ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

but I want to just select those rows directly like this:

```
SELECT location_id, 
FROM units
WHERE (DISTINCT castle_id);
```

---

*edit #2*

Here's a hypothetical:

- `units` has 100 rows
- 10 rows have `location_id: 1`
- 20 rows have `location_id: 3`
- etc...

in the 10 rows that have `location_id: 1` all 10 also have `castle_id: 76`

in the 20 rows that have `location_id: 3` 13 of them have `castle_id: 99` and 7 of them have `castle_id: 42`

I'm trying to determine when rows have identical `location_id` but the `castle_id` are not identical.

In this case I would skip over the 10 rows, keep the 20 that match my criteria, and then check the remaining 70.

---

*edit #3*
Here's a SQL Fiddle as requested: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad08

---

*edit #4*
Here's my new query:

```
    $units = DB::table('units AS u1')
    ->select('u1.location_id',
        'u1.previous_location_id', 
        'u1.id as unit_id',
        'u1.castle_id',
        'c1.guild_id',
        'u1.unit_type_id',
        'u1.current_health',
        'ut.damage',
        'ut.range')
    ->distinct()
    ->join('units AS u2', 'u1.location_id', '=', 'u2.location_id')
    ->join('castles AS c1', 'c1.id', '=', 'u1.castle_id')
    ->join('castles AS c2', 'c2.id', '=', 'u2.castle_id')
    ->join('unit_types AS ut', 'ut.id', '=', 'u1.unit_type_id')
    ->whereColumn([
        ['u1.castle_id', '<>', 'u2.castle_id'],
        ['c1.guild_id', '<>', 'c2.guild_id']
        ])
    ->orderBy('location_id')
    ->get();

    echo $units;
```

based off of the fubar's answer with another constraint added for when `guild_id` is the same.

Comment: Please explain with more detail what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @AndréMarcondesTeixeira I edited my original post with a hypothetical that should hopefully clarify what I'm trying to achieve in my query. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you create an SQL fiddle with seed data? That might help to visualise the data, and will certainly help with testing queries.

Comment: @fubar I added a SQL fiddle to my original post. I'm using laravel migrations to establish my DB and I don't have a lot of experience with SQL so I left it a bit simple...

Do you need me to add more tables or define the primary keys too?

Comment: @deja awesome. To clarify, `get the results where location_id is the same but castle_id is different` - based on the SQL fiddle you've just created, which rows would you expect to be returned? For rows 4 and 5, the location and castle id are the same, so would row 4 be returned, row 5, or neither?

Comment: @fubar I added the answer to my original post. I also fixed a typo in the fiddle and updated the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.location_id, u1.previous_location_id, u1.id as unit_id, u1.castle_id, c.guild_id, u1.unit_type_id, u1.current_health, ut.damage, ut.srange
FROM units u1
INNER JOIN units u2 ON (u1.location_id = u2.location_id)
INNER JOIN castles c ON (c.id = u1.castle_id)
INNER JOIN unit_types ut ON (ut.id = u1.unit_type_id)
WHERE u1.castle_id <> u2.castle_id
ORDER BY u1.id
```

Also see a working SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c9cb8/3

As for writing this using Laravel Query Builder, it'd look something like:

```
$units = DB::table('units AS u1')
    ->select('u1.location_id', 'u1.previous_location_id', 'u1.id as unit_id', 'u1.castle_id', 'c.guild_id', 'u1.unit_type_id', 'u1.current_health', 'ut.damage', 'ut.range')
    ->distinct()
    ->join('units AS u2', 'u1.location_id', '=', 'u2.location_id')
    ->join('castles AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'u1.castle_id')
    ->join('unit_types AS ut', 'ut.id', '=', 'u1.unit_type_id')
    ->whereColumn('u1.castle_id', '<>', 'u2.castle_id')
    ->groupBy('u1.id')
    ->orderBy('u1.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @fubar! This is exactly the solution I've been looking for.

I'm not sure how long it would have taken me to figure that out on my own, I've been struggling for days now!

Comment: it's breaking whenever I have an uneven amount of units at a location. When one `castle_id` has 5 units and the other `castle_id` has 1 unit, it will duplicate that 1 unit four more times(I think via join?) so that they both have the same amount.

I noticed because there's multiple units with identical primary key `id` which should never happen. I could add another constraint to only show unique `user_id` but I'm worried it will still duplicate these units in every query and that will take a lot of time and memory.

Comment: Can you update the SQL fiddle with sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I just did @fubar

Comment: It looks like using `GROUP BY u1.id` will fix this. I've updated my answer and SQL fiddle. Can you check and confirm?

Comment: I get this error: `SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "c.guild_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...on_id", "u1"."id" as "unit_id", "u1"."castle_id", "c"."guild...`

Comment: I don't know if it matters but later on I was going to trying to constrain by `guild_id` as well, and ignore any queries that had different `castle_id` but matching `guild_id` except in cases where both `guild_id` are null.

I was trying to approach it in pieces since it was giving me so much difficulty.

Comment: You didn't include all of the join tables in your SQL fiddle, so I haven't tested it with those. You could try using `SELECT DISTINCT...` instead, but I cannot test it without the data. But it sounds as though you have multiple rows in the other tables that match the `JOIN` criteria too.

Comment: I updated the original SQL Fiddle link with more data, as much as I could put in before I got an error.

Comment: [Your SQL query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad08/2) seems to work but I'm still getting an error in the Laravel Query Builder version

Comment: I've updated my answer and the query builder to use `DISTINCT`. That seems to work with your test data, removing all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the trick

```
SELECT id, location_id, castle_id FROM Units WHERE location_id IN (
    SELECT a.location_id FROM Units a
    JOIN Units b on (
       b.location_id = a.location_id AND 
       b.castle_id <> a.castle_id
    )
) ORDER BY location_id
```